# How to get the milliseconds from now() in Julia 0.4-pre?

Tags: julia, datetime-format

How to get the milliseconds from now()?

```
Dates.format(now(), "HH:MM:SS.sss")
```

gives

```
"18:32:11.000"
```

where the `.sss` part is always `.000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`now()` does't record milliseconds:

```
julia> @show x=now(); @show Dates.millisecond(x); @show Dates.second(x)
x = now() = 2015-09-04T19:09:32
Dates.millisecond(x) = 0
Dates.second(x) = 32
32
```

Comment: I think it is reasonable to expect that now() show milliseconds. Hope it will be implemented in a future Julia release.

Answer (score 0):

From [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408185/is-there-a-way-of-getting-now-at-least-to-millisecond-precision-in-julia?lq=1) I found your comment:

```
dt = Dates.unix2datetime(time())
Dates.millisecond(dt)
```

Which does the business. Cheers.