# Is there a way of getting 'now' (at least) to millisecond precision in Julia?

Tags: time, julia

Oftentimes, to know what happens when in your code you need high precision time to profile your app or for other reasons. [Apparently, now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407509/how-to-get-the-milliseconds-from-now-in-julia-0-4-pre) does not provide this feature, but is there another reasonably simple way to get 'now' to millisecond precision?

Comment: You should upvote and/or accept previous answers to your questions, if you'd like people to answer your new questions.

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated. Upvotes and alike are on the way. No worries ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the milliseconds from now() in Julia 0.4-pre?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407509/how-to-get-the-milliseconds-from-now-in-julia-0-4-pre)

Comment: @jch Please read the question that you find as possible duplicate more carefully. This is a completely different question from the other one. The other question is asking specifically about now() while this question is asking about a substitute that has the desired property, namely millisecond property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

```
help?> time

  time()

  Get the system time in seconds since the epoch, with fairly high (typically, microsecond) resolution.
```

So you can get the current `DateTime` using that.
But if you just want relative time, for e.g. profiling, you could use `tic()` and `toq()`, or `time_ns()` for really high accuracy, or just `time`.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I ended up with `Dates.unix2datetime(time())` to make the output human readable.